# Token Expiry based on user inactivity

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

So I am using django rest framework, and i am using simple jwt for token authentication, and i want to implement this (if the user hasn't been active on the website for 30 min then the token should expire and the user should be redirected to login page).

How should i do this, for your information i know about session authentication, however, i don't want to use it.

Note: If you have any other security methods/approaches i am open to hearing them since this is the only one that i know and i don't know how to implement it :-)

i have tried adding some fields in the payload, so i can use it to determine if the user is active or not, however idk how to make the server check it, since the only way that i check on the token is when the clinet make an api call

Comment: You cant, JWT tokens have to time out themselves unless you keep some sort of state on the server side (like a session cookie does) and then have some sort of job that checks some sort of last activity. This is one of the reasons why JWTs should never be used as session replacements in browsers. They were never designed for this.

Comment: Are your tokens tied to users? What code are you using to implement token auth now? How are you issuing the tokens to begin with? Generally, you cannot really revoke JWT tokens after they are issued; they simply expire at the expiration time declared when the token was created/issued. Maybe one simple (sloppy) way is to only issue the token with a 30 minute expiration and make the client get a new token. Or you can keep track of the last request made with a token in a database or cache layer, and choose to stop honoring the token if its last activity was more than 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Seems like a pain, is there any security method that can be implemented for token authentication aside from what i have asked, the same as the one in session authentication ( session expired based on user inactivity)